# Passing HTML Input Value To The Form Action in a New Window Using Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

Here is my javascript and php code.

**js**

```
function validate()
{
      myform.submit();
}
```

**php**

```
<form action="http://myurl/" method="post" name="myform" target="_blank">
       <input type="id" name="txtid" value="3">
       <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="validate()">
</form>
```

How can I pass the value of **txtid** to the form action so that my new window URL would have `http://myurl/3.` Any idea how to trick this?

Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function validate()
{
      //grabs the value of txtid
      txtid = $('#txtid').val();
      //uses var to redirect to the correct URL

      window.open(http://myurl/"+txtid);

}
```

Comment: Thank you Harry the url work fine, but the window not opened in a new window.

Comment: Great Job Harry..
Thank you very much. It work perfectly. :-)